# Changing the prompt in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, prompt

The line that I type in on Ubuntu looks like this:

```
username@DESKTOP-FOO:~$
```

when I want it to look like this:

```
username@userPC:~$
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using some virtualization on your "userPC" to create an Ubuntu environment, such as kvm or docker?

Comment: `username@DESKTOP-FOO:~$` is a command prompt .... it is not something that you type .... please try to clarify your post

Comment: why do you want the command prompt to be `username@userPC:~$`?

Comment: "DESKTOP-FOO" is the hostname of your computer. You can [simply change it](https://askubuntu.com/a/87687/631600).

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not fully understand your concern I can show you how you **change the prompt in general**.
There is an **environment variable** `PS1` that is used by your `~/.bashrc` file. This variable should contain this by **default**:

`\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`

Now you can feel free to **edit** this variable like this:

`PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@userPC:\w\$"`

It is not really elegant to do so but I did not understand where the "`userPC`" came from. The default (`\h`) takes your current **hostname** for the command line prompt.

This is however just for your **current session**.
If you want to make this permanent you should add the line stated above to your `~/.bashrc` file. Then it will be read automatically on logging in to a terminal.

Comment: @Kusalananda You are right. Thank you I will edit my post.